# How to render datetime.datetime with timezone to the HTML template in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

views.py

```
def myVideo(request, id):
    myVideo = MyVideo.objects.filter(id=id)
    serializerClassVideo = MyVideoSerializer(myVideo,many=True)
    print(type(myVideo[0].upload_time))
    print(myVideo[0].upload_time)
    myDate = datetime.now()
    print(type(myDate))
    print(myDate)

    return render(request, 'video.html', {
        'myDate': myDate,
        'videos': serializerClassVideo.data,
        }
    )
```

in the console, output like this:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>   
2018-05-30 19:52:20+00:00     # video.upload_time
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2018-08-05 13:47:57.653627    # datetime.now()
```

video.html

```
{{ myDate|date:"Y-m-d" }}
{{ v.upload_time|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```

On the html page, the first line above shows: 2018-08-05 which is great, and the second one, that I need, shows nothing.

I thought the issue should be related to the timezone in the "upload_time" field. What should I do if I don't want to change this field (which means I want to keep the timezone of "upload_time")?

Comment: Are you sure that `v.upload_time` holds some values?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sure! The output result in the console stands for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing the serialized data to your view, instead pass the objects list. Try this

```
 return render(request, 'video.html', {
        'myDate': myDate,
        'videos': myVideo,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you debugged the view.py?

what’s serializerClassVideo.data ‘s type?

Before you assure that “data” is what you want,you should not pass the “data “.

Try replacing

```
serializerClassVideo.data
```

with

```
myVideo
```

Comment: @mrhaoji make mistakes can make you be better.Therefore I think my routines can help a bit too.